# ExtJs 3.0 : Composite fields are not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I try to add composite fields to my web page using ExtJs. This is my code segment.

```
main_form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                bodyStyle : {
                    "background-color" : "#000000"
                },
                /*layout : {
                    type : 'vbox',
                    align : 'center'
                },
                defaults : {
                    labelWidth : 200,
                    padding : '0 0 0 25'
                },*/

                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'compositefield',
                    labelWidth : 120,
                    items : [ {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        forId: 'myFieldId',
                        text: 'Delivery Period',
                        margins: '0 0 0 10'
                        }, new Ext.form.DateField({
                        fieldLabel : 'From Date',
                        allowBlank : false,
                        width : 140,
                        name : 'fromDate',
                        hideLabel : true
                    }), new Ext.form.DateField({
                        fieldLabel : 'To Date',
                        allowBlank : false,
                        width : 140,
                        name : 'toDate',
                        hideLabel : true
                    }),
                    {
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel : 'Tour Code',
                        flex : 1
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        name : 'include_type',
                        fieldLabel : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                        emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                        editable : false,
                        hideLabel : true,
                        flex : 1
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        name : 'include_type',
                        fieldLabel : 'Tour Assign To',
                        emptyText : 'Tour Assign To',
                        editable : false,
                        hideLabel : true,
                        flex : 1
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        name : 'include_type',
                        fieldLabel : 'Assistant Name',
                        emptyText : 'Assistant Name',
                        editable : false,
                        hideLabel : true,
                        flex : 1
                    }, ]
                }, {
                    xtype : 'compositefield',
                    labelWidth : 120,
                    items : [ new Ext.form.TimeField({
                        fieldLabel : 'Day Start Time',
                        allowBlank : false,
                        width : 140,
                        minValue : '9:00 AM',
                        maxValue : '6:00 PM',
                        increment : 30,
                        hideLabel : true
                    }), new Ext.form.TimeField({
                        fieldLabel : 'Day End Time',
                        allowBlank : false,
                        width : 140,
                        minValue : '9:00 AM',
                        maxValue : '6:00 PM',
                        increment : 30,
                        hideLabel : true
                    }),
                    {
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel : 'Tour Code',
                        flex : 1
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        name : 'include_type',
                        fieldLabel : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                        emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                        editable : false,
                        hideLabel : true,
                        flex : 1
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        name : 'include_type',
                        fieldLabel : 'Tour Assign To',
                        emptyText : 'Tour Assign To',
                        editable : false,
                        hideLabel : true,
                        flex : 1
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        name : 'include_type',
                        fieldLabel : 'Assistant Name',
                        emptyText : 'Assistant Name',
                        editable : false,
                        hideLabel : true,
                        flex : 1
                    }, ]
                }

                ],
                /*buttons : [ {
                    text : 'Delete',
                    handler : function() {

                    }
                }, {
                    text : 'View',
                    handler : function() {

                    }
                }, {
                    text : 'New',
                    handler : function() {

                    }
                }, {
                    text : 'Exit',
                    handler : function() {
                        win3.hide();
                    }
                } ]*/
            });

            main_win = new Ext.Window({
                title: 'Tour Planning & Editing',
                layout: 'fit',
                //autoScroll: true,
                //y: 120,
                width: 480,
                height: 530,
                minWidth : 480,
                minHeight : 530,
                resizable : false,
                draggable : true,
                //modal: true,
                plain:true,
                //bodyStyle:'padding:8px;',
                //buttonAlign:'center',
                closeAction: 'hide',
                //floating: true,
                closable : true,
                items: [main_form]
            });
            main_win.show();
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't even load the window. I am usinf ExtJs 3.0

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur?  Surely if you think compositefield is the problem, you can come up with a more specific repro of the problem.

Comment: Firebug console says **TypeError: b[e] is not a constructor
 

...Dom.getViewWidth(),height:Ext.lib.Dom.getViewHeight()}}else{var m=d.getXY();k={x...**

Comment: Are you using the debug version of Ext?

Comment: Yes. i am using ext-all-debug.js

Comment: You're going to need to dig in. If it's looking for `b[e]`, you need to know what `b[e]` really is. It's been a long time since I've used Ext 3.x, but the error messages are difficult to interpret sometimes when you've just got a little mistake in your config setup.

Comment: Should I use new version of ExtJs?

Comment: It depends. There are substantial differences between the 3.x and 4.x framework, and it might be a big deal to migrate your app. If you're just starting it out, though, I think you should definitely consider 4.x, because you'll get more functionality, better performance in general, and better help here on stackoverflow.

Comment: this app is developed tow years ago b y someone.I have to do some modifications of if?

Answer (score 0):

Please, Don't ask me how. ;)

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Tour Planning & Editing',
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    plain:true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    items: [{
        xtype : 'form',
        layoutConfig : {
            align : 'middle', //top : Default, middle, stretch, stretchmax
            pack : 'center' //start : Default, center, end
        },
        defaults : {
            width : 400,
            height : 400,
            border : false,
        },
        items : [{
            xtype : 'compositefield',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            labelWidth : 120,
            items : [{
                xtype: 'label',
                forId: 'myFieldId',
                text: 'Delivery Period',
                margins: '0 0 0 10'
            }, {
                xtype : 'datefield',
                fieldLabel : 'From Date',
                allowBlank : false,
                width : 140,
                name : 'fromDate',
                hideLabel : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'datefield',
                fieldLabel : 'To Date',
                allowBlank : false,
                width : 140,
                name : 'toDate',
                hideLabel : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Tour Code',
                flex : 1
            }, {
                xtype : 'combo',
                name : 'include_type',
                fieldLabel : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                editable : false,
                hideLabel : true,
                flex : 1
            }, {
                xtype : 'combo',
                name : 'include_type',
                fieldLabel : 'Tour Assign To',
                emptyText : 'Tour Assign To',
                editable : false,
                hideLabel : true,
                flex : 1
            }, {
                xtype : 'combo',
                name : 'include_type',
                fieldLabel : 'Assistant Name',
                emptyText : 'Assistant Name',
                editable : false,
                hideLabel : true,
                flex : 1
            }]
        }, {
            xtype : 'compositefield',
            labelWidth : 120,
            items : [{
                xtype : 'timefield',
                fieldLabel : 'Day Start Time',
                allowBlank : false,
                width : 140,
                minValue : '9:00 AM',
                maxValue : '6:00 PM',
                increment : 30,
                hideLabel : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'timefield',
                fieldLabel : 'Day End Time',
                allowBlank : false,
                width : 140,
                minValue : '9:00 AM',
                maxValue : '6:00 PM',
                increment : 30,
                hideLabel : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                fieldLabel : 'Tour Code',
                flex : 1
            }, {
                xtype : 'combo',
                name : 'include_type',
                fieldLabel : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                emptyText : 'Delivery Vehicle',
                editable : false,
                hideLabel : true,
                flex : 1
            }, {
                xtype : 'combo',
                name : 'include_type',
                fieldLabel : 'Tour Assign To',
                emptyText : 'Tour Assign To',
                editable : false,
                hideLabel : true,
                flex : 1
            }, {
                xtype : 'combo',
                name : 'include_type',
                fieldLabel : 'Assistant Name',
                emptyText : 'Assistant Name',
                editable : false,
                hideLabel : true,
                flex : 1
            }]
        }]
    }]
}).show().center();
});
```

Comment: but id  doesn't.then i used extJs 3.4.then it works.but i can't use extJs 3.4

Comment: i am using this inside the button handler function.is it ok?

Comment: you can use this in button handler.
just use your handler function instead of "Ext.OnReady".